# Flot refuses to display data, but parses JSON labels fine

Tags: javascript, time, flot

I want to show a line chart with points being added dynamically to multiple series (i.e. show progress). y axis: shows a float with one number after the decimal point and on the x axi: time, ideally formatted to show hour:minute:second. This is live data obtained with Ajax, returned formatted as JSON.

The data returned:

```
    [
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#1 (ch un)",    "data": [1421941072,24.8]
    }
    ,
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#2 (2_ch2)",    "data": [1421941072,23.9]   
    }
    ,
    {
        "label": "s#2 ch#3 (N/A)",  "data": [1421941072,23.9]
    }
    ]
```

The Javascript is displaying one big point in the middle of the chart and the legends correctly, nothing else.

No JavaScript error. Valid JSON.
It's maddening.

The complete code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validity.js"></script>
    <link href="./flotexamples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fetchData() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/graphlist.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onDataReceived
        });

        function onDataReceived(series) 
        {
            data = series;     

            var options = 
            {
                series: 
                {
                    lines: 
                    {
                        show: true,
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                xaxis: 
                {
                    mode: "time"
                },
                yaxis: 
                {       
                    tickDecimals: 1
                }
            };

            $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
        }
    }

    // every 5 seconds
    var interval = 5000;

    var tid = setInterval(fetchData, interval);
    </script>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!
TIA,
Bert

Answer (score 1):

You're data isn't correctly formatted. If I'm interpreting your intention correctly, the data should probably be

```
[
{
    "label": "s#2 ch#1 (ch un)",    "data": [[1421941072,24.8]]
}
,
{
    "label": "s#2 ch#2 (2_ch2)",    "data": [[1421941072,23.9]]
}
,
{
    "label": "s#2 ch#3 (N/A)",  "data": [[1421941072,23.9]]
}
]
```

Note that the data property is an array of arrays.

Of course, with this construction each data series **is** just a single data point, but that's the only way I can interpret your question. I'm assuming that later updates will add more points to each series.

You might find this chapter on [flot](http://jsdatav.is/chap02.html) helpful.